# I want to call one child component from parent component spfx react

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react

I want to call SPFX react child component from parent component . But I am getting error while creating react component .

**Error:**

> Declaration or statement expected. Cannot find name 'div'. Type
>   'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement'.

**Child Component:**

```
export interface IDCLabelProps {
    thisCount: number;
    parenIid :number;
  }



    export default class ShopingCart extends React.Component<
    IDCLabelProps,any,any> 
{
      public constructor(props: IDCLabelProps, state: IDCLabelProps) {
        super(props);


      public render(): React.ReactElement<IDCLabelProps> {
        return (
          <div className={styles.shopingCart}>

          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

How can I fix this ?
Please help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. You need to close your constructor

```
   public constructor(props: IDCLabelProps, state: IDCLabelProps) {
      super(props);
    }
```

2. You probably named your component file *YourComponentName***.ts** -- with a **.ts** extension. Rename your file to *YourComponentName***.tsx** and it should magically start working.

I hope this helps?